# 2 UITableViews in one UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UIView` that will need to display two UITableViews, but they are never shown together, by using a `SegementedBar` you can toggle one or the other.

What would be the best way to handle this? Just create one `Table View Controller` and change the data source, or create 2 `Table View Controllers` and just hide one when the other is visible.

The 2 tables will have a completely different layout with different custom cells.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I would keep one datasource & delegate.

This means that all the delegate/datasource methods become more complicated BUT it means that you can retain the one to one relationship between viewController & view.

keep a reference to each of the table views

```
//vc.h
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
```

In the datasource/ delegate methods you need to account for the fact that the method needs to behave differently depending on which table view is in use. e.g.

```
//vc.m
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) {

        ...

    } else { // tableView == self.secondTableView

        ...
    }
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, however I have the same concerns as in rishi's post, it might cause a complex code structure, but it can also save me a lot of double code.

Comment: The bonus is you don't have two controllers, controlling one view which 'can' be a real pain when it goes wrong...

Comment: +1 - this implementation is much easier to adapt and follows Apple's design patterns for using UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: That's true too, I think I will try your way now, the code for each table cell isn't that complex actually, so it might be ok.

Comment: @woutr_be: note that while this approach seems a good way to go, it can get pretty complicated if your controller directly inherits from `UITableViewController`, which offers `tableView` property and has a `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` as well. If you plan to enhance features in future (search, maybe sorting?), the code can become tough to maintain and prone to bugs.

Comment: It's most unlikely that this part well get any features, it's just a table view with some cells.

Answer (score 6):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (tableView.tag == 1) {

        ...

    } else { // tableView == self.secondTableView

        ...
    }
}
```

tag could be assigned from the .xib.
so no need to have UITableVeiw variable in .h file.
Two table view in .xib needed

Answer (score 4):

Both approach has some pros and cons, but i will personally prefer approach having two separate controller.

Approach 1 - create one Table View Controller and change the data source

- This approach help in avoiding extra and repeated code.
- With this memory management is good as using one controller only.(Although this is not a big concern till then we won't have a lot of data.)
- Issue with this is having complexity.

Approach 2 - 2 Table View Controller

- With this approach definitely have extra and repeated code.
- But with this is less complexity.

Comment: I had the same concerns, while the first approach would save me a lot of code, I'm concerned it might cause a complex code structure.

Comment: @woutr_be - that's why i said that i will prefer second, as i want to avoid added complexity.

Comment: Thanks, for now I will go for the first approach, if it gets too complex I can still switch.

Answer (score 4):

In my current app, I need to have 4 `UITableView` in a single `UIViewController`, at once I've to show single table, based on the tab selected by the user, I've added four tables because, all of having different custom cells and functionality, to reduce complexity I took four.

The main benefit of this is that, each time you don't need to call `reloadData` to update a single table. I just need to properly handle table's show & hide flow. And believe me that's looks cool. Not flicking at all.

In my case, I am creating four tables by code only. And I make a method that will return me a table based upon a tag I've pass.

I keep `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as small as possible by dividing code into different functions.

Comment: this looks interesting.. What methods do you use / modify to achieve this effect? Code examples would be great.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte, I would not able to share any example with you. But you can make a method which will hide all the tables and only show particular table for which you're looking for. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can differentiate each table by its tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate `UITableViewControllers` and swap the views. It's less code, less complexity and it's the way Apple does it with the **TabBar**.

As for code complexity, there really isn't any. You simply do the following to switch views when the `UISegmentedControl`'s value has changed:

```
UIView *previousSuperview = myViewController1.view.superview;
myViewController2.view.frame = myViewController1.view.frame;
[myViewController1.view removeFromSuperview];
[previousSuperview addSubview:myViewController2.view];
```

Alternatively, you could set the corresponding view's `hidden` property.

Comment: I know this is somewhat delayed but I like your solution to this answer - my only question is do the seperate UITableViewControllers still act as the data source for their own table views

Comment: @MikeSimz Yes, by default they do just that. However, you can use a common data source if you want to by setting it on both `UITableView`s.