# json contents of multipletableviews in a uiviewcontroller not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have two tableviews in one viewcontroller and i'm fetching the contents from json, the tables are showing in the viewController with the header title of the tables but the details fetched from json is not showing. I checked on some tutorials too like http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=cabd75c0-ba00-48a9-811f-84d4a553f69c. Here is a sample code of my view controller

```
if (horizontalViewController == nil){
        horizontalViewController = [[HorizontalViewController alloc] init];
    }

if (horizontalViewController == nil){
       verticalViewController = [[VerticalViewController alloc] init];
    }

[horizontalTableView setDataSource:horizontalViewController];

[verticalTableView setDataSource:verticalViewController];


[horizontalTableView setDelegate:horizontalViewController];

[verticalTableView setDelegate:verticalViewController];


horizontalViewController.view = horizontalViewController.tableView;

verticalViewController.view = verticalViewController.tableView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload tableview.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

You can also put a check for different table view using below code

```
if ([tableView isEqual:tableViewName])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried reloading the tables but the contents are still not showing. I tried adding a subview to the view. 
[self.view addSubview: horizontalViewController.view];
i noticed when i do that for one, it will show the table and the contents but when i do for both, it will load the second table
[self.view addSubview: horizontalViewController.view];
[self.view addSubview: verticalViewController.view];

Comment: yes, i added a one table with the [self.view addSubview:horizontalViewController.view] included and the table loaded perfectly

Comment: Then when you need to show second tableview hide first tableview that is currently showing and add that in your view.

Comment: the two tables are to be displayed together in the view.

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649412/2-table-views-in-one-view

Comment: As i wrote earlier you can put check on the basis of tableView

Comment: OK.
Let me know if face any issue

Comment: thanks for the link, although it not what i'm looking for because i want the two tableviews to be shown together. I tried putting a check on the tableView and NSLog a comment but the comment is not visible. I noticed the two tables are showing because of the text in the header contents of the two tables are visible. Its just the data that i fetched from json in the tables that are not loading

Comment: try to add add both tableview in self.view instead of custom view.

Comment: i think you are not adding your tableview properly in super view.

Comment: thanks for your assitance. I've solved the issue. I'm using a custom cell for each tableview instead of adding several views.