# iPhone - multiple tables in one view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

I'm looking for guidances on building interface for my test application. I'm new to iPhone development so I'm not sure how should I approach it.

I want to display elements in multiple tables in one view. It should be possible to change table using swipe gesture and drag it's elements between each of tables. I plan to add some cool animation for dragging and adding new elements to tables. Should I use 'drawing 2d graphic' for that purpose or is there other way to do it (reuse tableview). Does anyone have any examples how to do it?

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking here. Are you wanting to drag stuff into different UITableViews or are you wanting to drag UITableViewCells around? If you just want to re-order UItableViewCells within their respective UITableViews - thats easy enough and done with a delegate method.

Comment: Maybe that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649412/2-table-views-in-one-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `UITableView`s in one `UIViewController`. Have each of their delegates and datasources in different model classes.
To drag things between them, you will need to create a table view cell view when you start holding on a table view cell so that when it is duplicated, you can move it around using a `UIGestureRecognizer`. Once you have that, to drop it into another `UITableView`, you'll need to check for its position and drop it in. Remember to update your model.

This is not very easy to do as you'll need to do many positioning and math stuff, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It would be complicated but a way to go...

Keep one datasource & delegate.This means that all the delegate/datasource methods become more complicated BUT it means that you can retain the one to one relationship between viewController & view.

keep a reference to each of the table views

//vc.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
```

In the datasource/ delegate methods you need to account for the fact that the method needs to behave differently depending on which table view is in use. e.g.

//vc.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) {

        ...

    } else { // tableView == self.secondTableView

        ...
    }
}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: This is basically a re-post of [the answer by @Damos in the answer linked to in the comments above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10649628/467105).  It's an unnecessary duplicate answer.